# Hexagon Mayhem: Geometry Challenge

Tags: geometry

Suppose that there is a regular hexagon $UVWXYZ$. Suppose that $A$ is the region that is common to the triangles that are formed $VYZ$ and $UWX$. If the area of $A$ is 19, find the area of the regular hexagon $UVWXYZ$.

Answer (score 1):

The area is a kite. Three such kites make up one of the six equilateral triangles that the regular hexagon naturally decomposes into. Therefore its area is $19\cdot18$.

Comment: Oh yeah thats true. Thanks!

Comment: How would the area be less than 19. Wouldn't it be 19*18 = 342?

Comment: @math101 Yep! I thought that $19$ was the area of the whole hexagon and we were looking for the small area. I'll edit.